# Sylow $p$-subgroups and their normalizers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $H$ and $K$ be Sylow $3$- and $5$-subgroups, respectively, of a finite group $G$.  Suppose $H$ and $K$ have orders $3$ and $5$, respectively.

Prove that if $3$ divides the order of $N(K)$ (the normalizer of $K$ in $G$), then $5$ divides the order of $N(H)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: apply Sylow theory: in $N_G(K)$ there must be a conjugate of $H$, show that this implies that $N_G(H)$ contains a conjugate of $K$.

Since $3$ divides its order, the subgroup $N_G(K)$ contains a (cyclic) subgroup $S$ of order $3$ (apply Cauchy's Theorem).

Step 1. $S$ centralizes $K$ (that is, $S \subseteq C_G(K) \subseteq N_G(K)$ (where the second inclusion is always true))

> We will apply the "$N/C$"-theorem: $N_G(K)/C_G(K)$ injects homomorphically in $Aut(K)$, and since $|K|=5$, $K \cong C_5$, whence $Aut(K)\cong C_4$. This shows that index$[N_G(K):C_G(K)]$ is *even*, and we conclude that $3 | |C_G(K)|$. So $S$ can be found in the centralizer of $K$ in $G$.

Step 2. $S \subseteq C_G(K) \iff K \subseteq C_G(S)$.

> For all $s \in S$ and $k \in K$: $s^{-1}ks=k \iff k^{-1}sk=s$

Step 3. $N_G(H)$ contains a conjugate of $K$.

> Since $S$ has order $3$ and also the Sylow $3$-subgroup $H$ has order $3$, there is a $g \in G$ with $S^g=H$. Hence by the previous step, $K \subseteq C_G(H^g)=C_G(H)^{g^{-1}}$. And this gives $K^g \subseteq C_G(H)$. But always $C_G(H) \subseteq N_G(H)$, so we are done.

Step 4. $|N_G(H)|$ is divisible by $5$.

> $|K^g|=|K|=5$ and apply the previous step.

In general the following holds.

**Proposition** Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that $q \not \equiv 1$ mod $p$. Assume that the order of the finite group $G$ is divisible by $p$ and $q$, but not by higher powers of these primes. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $Q \in Syl_q(G)$. Then $p$ divides $|N_G(Q)|$ implies $q$ divides $|N_G(P)|$.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not convinced that this is likely to be very helpful!

Comment: Ok, will write out the solution later ...

Comment: Nicky --  I was the one who asked.  Looks like you gave some good hints.  Just came back from a master teaching conference.  I'll look at your hints more closely tomorrow.  I think I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Ok take your time let me know if you have any questions

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing.

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing.  This problem is from Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra. Unfortunately, Gallian's hint for this problem was not helpful at all.  It said "Use the fact that HK is a cyclic subgroup of order 15."  That is obvious, given the orders of H and K.  H X K is a (cyclic) group of order 15, isomorphic to HK.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've been out of graduate school for 20 years and now teach online Calculus at a community college.  I just want to keep my brain working on these problems (or if I am insane enough to pursue aPhD at the age of 59).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution.

First, we need to know that all groups of order $15$ are abelian (in fact, cyclic). This is a standard exercise, so I will not give the proof.

Next, we note that since $3$ divides the order of $N_G(K)$, it has a subgroup of order $3$. It also has a normal subgroup of order $5$ (namely $K$), and hence it has a subgroup of order $15$.

This means that $G$ has a subgroup of order $15$, and hence that $G$ has an element of order $5$ which commutes with an element of order $3$. In other words, for some subgroup of order $3$, let's call it $Q$, we get that there is an element of order $5$ in $N_G(Q)$. But now, we also assumed that $3$ was the order of a Sylow subgroup of $G$, and all Sylow subgroups have normalizers of the same order, which proves the claim.